# Job prospects for Red Teaming in cloud security?

Tags: cloud-computing, career

I want to make my career in cyber security, but am confused which field to choose. According to this Burning Glass report,

https://www.burning-glass.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Fastest_Growing_Cybersecurity_Skills_Report.pdf

Cloud security is 2nd most demanded field with least supply. *I don't care about Application security because I hate coding.* The report doesn't contain any information about red team, but I have strong interest in this field. Can anyone tell **its demand and supply with comparison to cloud security?**

Comment: I am not a professional in information security by any means, but if you hate coding i think you will have a pretty bad time in most of the fields with a technical aspect. As from what i know, red teaming as well as cloud security may include the development of custom scripts and/or the extension of tools.

Comment: I CAN code. In fact I've solved many intermediate level questions on geeksforgeeks. But despite that I don't like it and don't wanna brainstorm in it forever. Its ok if i have to do a little

Comment: Are you asking how many cloud red team professionals there are and how many are being asked for? I'm not that's answerable. There is a general large gap in the supply and need for security professionals.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding red teaming specifically, in comparison to cloud security there is a lot less demand because very few companies do true red teaming. Most companies use a cloud service in some way so they will need people to secure and analyze this but unless you work for a consultancy or large company most won't employ internal red teamers.

However I have to agree with the others, I'm sorry to say that if you don't like coding I don't think either of these roles will be a good fit for you. (Good) Red teaming involves creating custom command and control payloads to circumvent anti virus and exfiltrate data etc. So you really need to be good at coding, networking and windows/linux API. Cloud security often involves a lot automation so you will need to create and manage scripts.

In general, I really would avoid basing your future job prospects on which has most 'supply & demand' especially when it comes to specifc job titles as opoosed to general field or interests. Because first of all these fields and technologies change quite a bit over the years. The other problem is that to be good you continually need to be learning new techniques and if you are not that passionate about it you will get bored quickly. Also bear in mind that with all these cyber security roles there is a lot of *boring stuff* as well. You may be a pentester and spend 30% of your time doing technical stuff but the rest you will be writing reports, checking other peoples reports, sitting in meetings with clients and doing presentations, creating documentation etc.

Based on your post I really don't think red teaming would be a good fit for you. You may find that less technical roles likes risk, pre-sales and the like may be a better fit to avoid the coding aspect.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, there's enough demand in any infosec field for you to find a job in the specialty you want. But that depends on where you want to live and the kind of businesses that are around.

If you do not like coding, you might dislike cloud security even more.

At my workplace (a infosec audit and consultancy company), most of the new applicants want to do red team or pentesting, because that's what appears to be the most fun. However, demand in red teaming is pretty low, so low it does not even appear in the report you cite. Pentesting can be integrated into more general audits (web, app, infrastructure) and the skills can be useful in incident response.

When we recruit, the most important "skill" we look for is curiosity. Because the technical skill level out of school is so low, it does not really matter. What is important (for us) is how fast you will learn the trade while on the job. Keep in mind that half the trade is composed of social skills (writing reports, interacting with clients). Our pentesters only spend about 10% to 20% of their time actually performing pentests.

If, however, you want to work in a company developing products or services, things will be different. I think the report you cite match more those profiles. But you might as well forget red teaming, because the only positions available in the companies looking for internal red teams will not be for juniors.

Anyway, that's only from my point of view (too long for a comment), YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you "hate coding", then it's best to pick the 3rd most in demand skill according to the report - Risk Management.

Cloud security will require software programming skills to do automation, whereas Red teaming will also require coding skills to develop custom tools for offensive purposes.